# Change background color on <a> hover

Tags: html, css

I have a landing page with a welcome title.
On `hover` I would like not only the `<a>` text to change cover but the background  of `<header>`  to change background color.

I understand you can't alter the parent tag on hover of a child element.
I did try using a sibling div but this didn't work either.

```html
<header>
  <div>
    <h1>This is a <a href="#">link</a> to go somewhere.</h1>
  </div>
  <div id="headerhover"></div>
</header>
```

Comment: A javascript solution would also be great if this is easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>You just need to use `hover` state for `a`</strike>

See this snippet below:

```css
h1 a {
  color: black
}
h1 a:hover {
  color: green;
  background-color: red
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div>
    <h1>This is a <a href="#">link</a> to go somewhere.</h1>
  </div>
</header>
```

After a careful reading, I understand you want the parent to change the background,  It cannot be done by pure CSS. Because CSS only supports styling in cascading direction, not up.

However in this case if we play with [`pointer-events`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events) it is possible, take a look:

```css
header {
  pointer-events: none;
}
header:hover {
  background: yellow
}
header h1 a {
  color: black;
  pointer-events: auto;
}
header h1 a:hover {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div>
    <h1>This is a <a href="#">link</a> to go somewhere.</h1>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: Thanks this is perfect, never needed to use the attribute 'pointer-events'

Answer (score 0):

jQuery Solution, would be

```js
$('a').hover(
  function() {
    $(this).closest('header').css({'background':'red'});
  }, 
  function() {
    $(this).closest('header').css({'background':'yellow'});
  }
);
```

```css
header {width:100%; height:1000px; background:cyan;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
 <div><h1>This is a <a href="#">link</a> to go somewhere.</h1></div>
        <div id="headerhover"></div>
</header>
```

Comment: Thanks! This is great, I will use the css solution for the sake of simplicity but this does what I needed also.